# Secure Https Channel form login

Tags: safecracker, members, login, ssl

I have a section of my site where users login and can create and edit profiles. Theses profiles are edited through a channel form and are behind a login.
I have moved this section of the site over to https recently and it all works ok but my issue is the member login

```
{exp:member:login_form return="staff/index"}
```

This is insecure and give the user a browser prompt stating that before login.Is there a way to secure this login

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to force HTTPS. If you have a valid certificate, you really should force your entire site to use the protocol, the **only** reason not to is if you need to support very very legacy devices (think old dumb phones). In your .htaccess file, **before** your index.php rewrite, add something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you **really** just want to force it on one page, you can add a condition like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/staff\/index [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will only force the `staff/index` base URI to use the HTTPS protocol.